# Locate an element by uib-tooltip in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I'm having issues locating 'events' on our platform. Each time an event is created, a div card is added to the page at the end of the events. Ideally I'd like to run tests in parallel so picking up the event based on location would be difficult depending on the timing. The tooltip will change based off of the name each time.

```
<div class="caption__name ng-binding" uib-tooltip="Name Here">Name Here</div>
```

Edit - additional clickable code:

```
<div class="card__caption" ng-click="goToEvent(event)"><!--<div class="card__caption" ui-sref="backend.parent.event.builder.update({id: event.id})">--><div class="caption__name ng-binding" uib-tooltip="Basic Automation without companion">Basic Automation without companion</div><!-- ngIf: event.location.venue --><div class="caption__location ng-binding ng-scope" uib-tooltip="House of Blues" ng-if="event.location.venue">House of Blues</div><!-- end ngIf: event.location.venue --><!-- ngIf: !event.location.venue --><div class="caption__date ng-binding">Jul 25th 2017 - Jul 27th 2017</div></div>
```

Comment: Please show more content plus more rows of tips.  I can't figure out a good answer based on the lone isolated example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locating an element by the value of an attribute is usually pretty straightforward to do with a *CSS selector locator*:

```
$('[uib-tooltip="Name Here"]').getText();
```

Or, if you are only interested in last element with the `uib-tooltip`, you can do:

```
$$("[uib-tooltip]").last().getText();
```

Note that if you want to make things more organized and modular and, if you are going to locate elements by the `uib-tooltip` more, it might be a good idea to [*make a custom locator out of it*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137585/protractor-custom-locators).

That said, this answers the question in this specific scope only - seeing the complete HTML source of the page might help to generate more or/and better options.

Comment: I added the code for the div that needs to be clicked in the original question. I'm still having issues finding a specific div based off of the name and clicking it. Any recommendations?

Comment: @Kelsey okay, if you follow the code in the answer, how would it fail? Also, does adding a hardcoded `browser.sleep()` delay make any difference? (trying to see if this is a timing issue - shot in the dark). Thanks.

Comment: I was able to use  `$('[uib-tooltip="Name Here"]');` to identify the event in the page object file and then use a click event to open the correct item. This will work for the time being. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If `caption__name` is unique:

```
div.caption__name
```

If there are more than one then either scope under a stable element or use `last-child`(css) or `.last`(xpath) to pick out the last, something like

```
div.caption__name:last-child
```

but that may not work and I think I still would want to see if there is a parent element around this set of divs for this card, and if **that** element has an attribute I can use and target with `last-child`, if so I would then be able to use something more like

```
div.card:last_child div.caption__name
```

You say the row is added dynamically  but is last, at the end, so last-child if suitable for that.